Using tabs in Quarto and R
I want to add tabs in Quarto. I will have 8 tabs, so i decide to make aloop in order to generate sections of text and print a dotplot under each tab.
I try the following code. The code must print dotplot under each tab
```r

# Ligands-Receptors Couples (CellPhonDB)
::: {.panel-tabset .nav-pills}
```{r}
#| label: dotplotcpdb
#| fig.height: 10
#| fig.width: 18
#| results: 'asis'
 templateDtpcpdb <- "## %s
 Below are displayed the most significant interactions for the %s
 "
 for (i in 1:length(Fatlaslianacpdb)){
   cat('\n')
   cat(sprintf(templateDtpcpdb, unique(Fatlas.seu[[i]]$Sample), unique(Fatlas.seu[[i]]$Sample)))
   print(dotplotliana(i, Fatlaslianacpdb, Fatlaslianacpdb.sign))
  cat('\n')
}```
:::
```    

Nothing is displayed when using this code. Can you please tell me where there is an error?
Thank you for your help

Without any sample code and MWE it is very difficult to help.

Here is a very way using purrr::walk():
---
format: html
---

# Ligands-Receptors Couples (CellPhonDB)


::: panel-tabset
```{r}
#| results: asis
#| label: dotplotcpdb

row_nr = 1:8
library(ggplot2)
purrr::walk(row_nr,
      \(x) {
        cat('### Plot', x, '\n\n')
        print(mtcars[x:(x+1),] |> 
                ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
                geom_point())
        
        cat('\n\n')
      })
```

:::


